# if sql query is incorrect than program compile successfully or not in java

Tags: java, sql, exception

if error in MySQL query or not correct MySQL query than program is compile successfully or not, no any other error in program just like database connectivity.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It compiles, just throws a runtime exception. Search the web. Also, take a [tour].

Answer (score 0):

All compile-time errors that would cause compilation to fail are documented in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html). So long as an SQL query is a well-formed string with valid escape sequences where appropriate for Java source, it will compile.

For example, the following will compile:

```
String mySQLStatement = "SELCT ** FROM `nonExistentTable` WHERE";
```

in spite of it being absurdly syntactically wrong.

However, syntax errors in using classes that let you build an SQL statement programatically may result in compile errors, if your use of them does not agree with return/parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

When there is error in sql query it won't throw compile time error reason being is that , query is considered as string while compiling but while executing it will throw SQL Exception error.

While compiling it will check all the syntax of java code but while executing it will check syntax of SQL.

Hence if there is problem with SQL query it will throw an error at run time.